# Hyphenation of words with accents

Tags: hyphenation

I know that hyphenating words with accents produces an error in LaTeX. So what can I do in such an occasion? I am facing a problem like that in my text where I use the Linux Libertine O font as the main font. The character is a greek alpha with an accent.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: No minimal example to write here. I am getting a latex error Improper hyphenation will be flushed , when I am trying to use for example things like `\hyphenate{μετα-ευριστικός}` (words with accents)

Comment: @Paramar: Does wrapping what you have with `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} \hyphenate{μετα-ευριστικός} \end{document}` reproduces the problem? If so than that would be a MWE. If not, then it needs to be expanded until it reproduces the problem.

Comment: Please make a complete document starting `\documentclass` and ending `\end{document}`  showing all packages loaded. The first sentence of your question isn't true LaTeX can hyphenate such words, the packages you use to set up the greek fonts are supposed to set up greek hyphenation, so your document is mis-configured in some way but if you do not show us an example document it is impossible to guess what is wrong. Also are you using pdflatex or xelatex or lualatex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the *only* hyphenation point you want in "μεταευριστικός" is after "μετα", then the following (in XeLaTeX) will work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainlanguage{greek}

\begin{otherlanguage*}{greek}
\hyphenation{μετα-ευριστικός}
\end{otherlanguage*}

\begin{document}

\parbox{1pt}{\hspace{0pt}μεταευριστικός}

\end{document}
```

The `\parbox{1pt}{\hspace...}` is just in order to force XeTeX to do all possible hyphenations.

Note that the `\hyphenation` command is language dependent, so you have to state hyphenation exceptions in the proper language environment. If you use only one language or the exceptions are only for the main language, the `\hyphenation` declaration can be put after `\begin{document}`.

[image]

Without the `\hyphenation` declaration, the result would have been

[image]

Comment: We are near the solution. The code you proposed me correctly separates the word at μέτα but doesn't solve the problem. In my text I had μεταευριστικός that needed to be separated in the middle of a paragraph. With parbox it gets separated but falls over the next word of the text and the second part of the word isn't written in the beggining of the next line. What do you propose to solve this?

Comment: @Paramar The `\parbox` is *only* to show the hyphenation points; you *mustn't* use it in your code.

Comment: Hmm, I tried only adding the \hyphenation part. My text compiles with Xelatex but the hyphenation mistakes still exist. Any idea? The packages used are: `\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\greekfontsf[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\greekfonttt[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguages{english}
\begin{otherlanguage*}{greek}
\hyphenation {σταθε-ρές}
\hyphenation{μεταευ-ριστικές}
\end{otherlanguage*}`

Comment: @Paramar Not without a real example. If you're using `ucharclasses` for setting the language, you've been warned. `;-)`

Comment: Following your advice I erased ucharclasses

Comment: @Paramar Add to the question, not in comments; and an example of a paragraph with "wrong" hyphenation is needed.

Comment: One last question and then I will Add to the question. Is there a way to just force Latex to hyphenate a word in an appropriate way. I thought that was the role of `\hyphenate` but apparently that is not the case. Does anything from the code I have written above look suspicious to you? It is difficult for me to find an example because I don't really know what is wrong. In my pdf hyphenation errors start at page 15 inside an enumeration but if I separate and just write page 15 by itself there is no error. However I will try to create one example.